# Concept and idea behind FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have created my **MainActivity** with four tabs as Fragment . Someone guide me to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter and use a ViewPager inside it. I have searched on google but don't find a good resource or I say i didn't understand the concept behind the coding .

Show some sample codes and explain it in detail please. It will be very greatful if it contains TabActivity like structure .

I need four fragment in my MainActivity which can switch like as we do in TabActivity. And one more thing .

Thanks in Advance.